# Powerpoint and VBA - "Modular" presentation

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Let me explain the context:
I have a huge training material (some 750 slides, for a two-days training) to rework.
Even though it is considered a "in-depth training", not all the material is useful for a given two-days session. Depending on the trainees profile, a chapter can either be fully presented with practical advices, or only the overview is given.
This means, before every session, I review the material and manually select which slides will be presented/hidden according to the trainees profile.

As I've never used VBA macros on Powerpoint, I was wondering if it is possible to, say, "tag" the slides with one or several roles (e.g. slide for "system designer", slide for "certification specialist", slide for "system designer + certification manager", etc...), and then by a simple form, check the "tags" you want and automatically generate the related presentation with the tagged slides accordingly.

For example, if for a given training session I have no system designer, but I have certification specialists and managers, I will check "certification specialist" and "certification manager" and it will generate me the presentation with only the slides that have those tags.

I hope I was clear enough...

Many thanks in advance !

Morgan

Comment: It's considered good practice on Stack Overflow to make an attempt at solving a problem yourself and then ask about any specific issues you encounter. As it stands this question just sounds like you're asking people to do your work for you.

Comment: I'm simply asking if anyone know whether this is doable, or eventually if there is a viable wayaround. I would not dare ask for the solution without having done some research myself, despite my mediocre programming skills...

Comment: [This MS link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff745958%28v=office.14%29.aspx) might be helpful. It appears you can access slides by index, slideID, name..

Comment: Thank you for the link, it helps indeed !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this would be possible.  Using VBA, you could tag the slides (there actually ARE things called tags in the object model), then have a routine make any slides tagged a certain way visible and all others invisible.

To add a tag to the currently selected slide, you'd do something like this to identify all of the currently selected slides as being material for Certification Specialists.  Slides can have multiple tags, so you can mod the same code to make it tag them for the other types of audience as well.

```
Sub TagAsCertificationSpecialist()

    Dim x As Long

    For x = 1 To ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Count
        ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange(x).Tags.Add "CertificationSpecialist", "YES"
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I did not know tags existed! It helps a lot :-)